# C# List<(string,string)> matching and replacing values

Tags: c#, list, match, recursive-query, enumerable

I'll try to explain this as simple as I can, it's quite a specific issue. I've been using F# for a while now and this may be causing me to get confused. What i'm trying to do is essentially (or close to) a typical recursive match statement but i'm doing this in C#.

I have a list(string s1, string s2) i'll call this list1. This consists of labels and true values.

Example:
"great cause", "1";
"hyper sensitive", "2";
"increased pertinence", "3"
"greater sensitive", "4";

I then have another list i'll call List2. This is a list of partial strings. For example:

"cause"; "greater"; "hyper"; "pertinence"

I want to match on the list1 (string s1,string s2) and replace the List2 string(or generate a new list) with the s2 value where s1.contains(List2).

So using the same examples as above, my end goal would be a list with the following values:
"1"; "4"; "2"; "3"

Edit:
I suppose in some ways this is kind of like using my List1 as a lookup table if this were a SQL query, and I want to get the actual value not the lookup code (in this case the string is the lookup code and the number is the true value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ with `Where` and `Select` looking like this:

```
var list1 = new List<(string, string)>
{
    ("great cause", "1"), ("hyper sensitive", "2"), ("increased pertinance", "3"), ("greater sensitive", "4")   
};

var list2 = new List<string>{"cause", "greater", "hyper", "pertinance"}; // fixed typos from the post.
var result = list2
    .Where(s => list1.Any(t => t.Item1.Contains(s)))
    .Select(s => list1.First(t => t.Item1.Contains(s)).Item2)
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result)); // prints "1, 4, 2, 3"
```

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what i was looking for thank you.

Comment: @Anthonyder was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the best bet would be using a dictionary for l1 instead, have something like:

```
           var l2 = new string[] { "cause", "greater", "hyper", "pertinance" }.ToList();
           dic.Add("great cause", "1");
           dic.Add("hyper sensitive", "2");

           for (int i = 0; i < l2.Count; i++)
           {
               l2[i] = dict1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Contains(l2[i])).Value;
           }
```